# Ошибка при выводе диалогового окна

Tags: android

Взял код простейшего файлового менеджера https://habrahabr.ru/post/109486/
Разделил экран на 2 части - 2 фрагмента, в которых независимо от друг друга можно открывать свои папки. На клик по папке хочу выводить диалоговое окно, и спрашивать пользователя что сделать - открыть ее, или скопировать в папку второго фрагмента. В этот момент ловлю ошибку. Не могу понять почему она вылетает и как ее исправить.

```
public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
    private List<String> directoryEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
    private File currentDirectory = new File("/");
    private TextView myTextView;

    public Fragment1(){

    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manager, null);
        myTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleManager);
        browseTo(new File("/"));
        return v;
    }
    private void upOneLevel(){
        if(currentDirectory.getParent() != null) {
            browseTo(currentDirectory.getParentFile());
        }
    }

    private void browseTo(final File aDirectory){
        if (aDirectory.isDirectory()){
            currentDirectory = aDirectory;
            fill(aDirectory.listFiles());
            myTextView.setText(aDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file://" + aDirectory.getAbsolutePath()));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    //fill list
    private void fill(File[] files) {
        directoryEntries.clear();

        if (currentDirectory.getParent() != null)
            directoryEntries.add("..");
        for (File file : files) {
            directoryEntries.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.row, directoryEntries);
        setListAdapter(directoryList);
    }
    //when you clicked onto item
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        final String selectedFileString = directoryEntries.get(position);
        final File clickedFile = new File(selectedFileString);

        View.OnClickListener okButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(selectedFileString.equals("..")){
                    upOneLevel();
                } else {
                    if (clickedFile != null)
                        browseTo(clickedFile);
                }
            }
        };
        View.OnClickListener cancelButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        };
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Подтверждение") //title
                .setMessage("Что сделать с файлом "+ selectedFileString + "?") //message
                .setPositiveButton("Открыть", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) okButtonListener) //positive button
                .setNegativeButton("Скопировать", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) cancelButtonListener) //negative button
                .show(); //show dialog
    }
}
```

Через дебагер узнал что крашится именно на строке

```
.setPositiveButton("Открыть", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) okButtonListener)
```

Скажите пожалуйста из-за чего ошибка и как ее исправить.

Comment: Ошибка то какая?

Comment: @Андроид Андроид 

1) Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement


2) Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка из за того, что вы `View.OnClickListener okButtonListener` пытаетесь привести к `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. Это разные классы, которые друг с другом не связаны. Измените на:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener okButtonListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(selectedFileString.equals("..")){
            upOneLevel();
        } else {
            if (clickedFile != null)
                browseTo(clickedFile);
        }
    }
};
```

И тоже самое с `cancelButtonListener`.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно так. 
Скажите пожалуйста, как вы нашли эту ошибку? На что вы обратили внимание в первую очередь, на какой ресурс зашли? я хочу научиться сам находить ошибки в своем коде.

Comment: С опытом придёт. Просто научитесь читать логи в `AndroidMonitor`. Те ошибки, которые вы указали в комментарии не имеют отношения к проблеме. У вас там что-то типа `ClassCastException` должен быть с указанием точной строки кода, где это произошло. Посмотрите внимательно ещё раз.